# Unable to open app on heroku. React, node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

so I've tjried several solutions I found here and unfortunately none of them seemed to work. I have an app which I have deployed on heroku. Frontend in react.js backend in node. When I run

```js
heroku open
```

I receive an error 404 in console. Heroku logs show error code 503 and "Failed at the @ start script". I am not sure what might be a problem, here is my json

```js
{
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "4.17.1",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "react": "^16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^3.4.1",
    "reactstrap": "^8.5.1",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "uuidv4": "^6.1.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "client": "npm run start --prefix client",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
    "heroku-postbuild": "NPM_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
  
  },
  "build": "cd client && yarn install && yarn build"
}
```

Please advise.

Comment: What _else_ do the logs show? Your `start` script says `node index.js`. Is that command generating any errors?

Comment: * server.js, sorry I amended. Yes, it shows also "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/app/client/build/index.html'" however index.html is where it should be.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the issue is fixed now. The problem was version or react-scripts in packaje.json. It differed in client and server side. Once I made sure the version it the same I rebuild the app and it opened correctly. Hope that helps someone in the future.